# linux c++ using existing browser components?

Tags: c++, linux, browser, chromium, ubuntu

I want to build a program in c++ ( on Linux ) that can show webpages etc.

but i dont want to build an html converter. are there some solutions like c# that let you use the webbrowser engine from another browser so your actually something like 'chromium' in your window (or a other engine). And if this is possible what engines do you recommend?

it would be really cool if they also support html5 with webgl but thats not a pre.

Thanks :)

Comment: [QtWebkit](https://qt-project.org/wiki/QtWebKit) -- of course it requires you to use Qt but with C++ on Linux, Qt is one of the sanest choices anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to use WebKit. Since there are existing bindings for WebKit to Qt and to GTK, it's probably easiest if you build the rest of your program using one of those.

WebKit is the rendering engine used by Chrome (among others), so at least from a viewpoint of rendering HTML, this should give results fairly similar to using Chrome. Note, however, that Chrome uses Google's own V8 Javascript engine. By default, WebKit uses the JavascriptCore engine, so for Javascript it wouldn't be at all surprising to see at least some differences between the two.

Comment: Qt is a 'framework' you can also use for building interfaces and much more right?

Comment: @user1971401: Yes. GTK is more or less the same, though not as all-encompassing as Qt.